# Isomap is faster than MDS

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, dimensionality-reduction

In Scikit-Learn implementation, Isomap algorithm runs faster that Multi Dimensional Scaling on the S-Curve dataset as illustrated [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/manifold/plot_compare_methods.html). In the third stage of algorithm, the [implementation uses Partial Eigen Value decomposition](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/manifold.html#complexity) instead of MDS which is the version proposed by the [researchers](http://www.sciencemag.org/content/290/5500/2319.full).

I'm  a bit lost at how Partial Eigen value decomposition does the same job as MDS. Can anyone throw some light over this ?

Comment: The decomposition is precisely what MDS would do. You can see this by noting the (Euclidian) equivalence between classical MDS and PCA. PCA simply performs an eigendecomposition on the covariance matrix (or probably an SVD), so that's exactly what to expect here.